# Use Environment Variable in the same process that assigned it

Tags: environment-variables

I have an Installer that assigns an Environment variable using setx command

Afterwards, that installer invokes a command line that uses this enviroment variable but in that context the variable is still empty.

If I invoke the command line independently the variable is read properly.

Why is that? and how can I overcome that?

Answer (score 1):

I've experimented extensively with SETX. Variables set via SETX cannot be seen in the process or script that sets them, unless you programmatically re-read the pertinent Registry key.